# Javascript Promises dosent work like I expect

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand promises and getting a bit confused here. I am playing with different scenarios and I stack on one of them. Why doesn't `let third = function()` wait for `let second = function()` to stop counting?

```js
let first = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('first');
            resolve()
        }, 3000)
    })
}

let second = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let iter = 7
        console.log(iter);
        for (let i = 0; i <= iter; i++) {
            (function(n) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    console.log('hi');
                    console.log(n);
                }, 400 * i);
            }(i)*i);
        }
        console.log('seco');
        resolve();
    })
}    

let third = function() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log('thir');
        resolve()
    })
};

let scenario = function() {
    first()
    .then(() => second())
    .then(() => third())
} 
scenario()
```

Comment: Your `second()` function resolves before all the timeouts print. That `resolve()` is what the `third()` function "waits" for, not the scheduled `setTimeout()` callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@johnnybigH, 
The second function resolve's outside of timeout so technically it will not wait for timeout function to complete as you are resolving it out of setTimeout. Now 2nd one is resolved so it is going for the execution of the third function.
What you can do is inside of 2nd function for the loop. look for the last iteration and resolve the end function.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= iter; i++) {
        (function(n) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log('hi');
                console.log(n);
            if(i == iter) resolve();
            }, 400 * i);
        }(i)*i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` doesn't wait for the function to return - it just schedules it to be executed later. The call to `setTimeout` returns immediately and your task finishes after that.

To wait for the scheduled function to execute after a certain period of time, call `resolve()` at the end of the delayed function. That way the promise will only be completed once the scheduled function executes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior.

The setTimeouts will not demonstrate expected order since the functions themselves resolved in the order as defined in the promise. Just replace the setTimeouts with console.log()'s and you will see the order executed as defined.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `for` loop won't wait for your `setTimeout` method to execute. Every time the `for` loop encounters the `setTimeout` method, JS will call the event loop and place it there (to be executed once it times out) and move forward. That's why it calls your `resolve` before printing the `console.log` statements from the `setTimeout` method. 
For an analogy, check this

```
for (let i= 0; i< 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('I am inside');
  }, 1000);

  console.log('I am outside')
}
```

It will print `I am outside` first (5 times) and then `I am inside`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create this effect, but you need to put your `resolve()` in its own `setTimeout()`, adjusting the second parameter such that there is sufficient time for the other timeouts to complete.

```js
const first = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('First promise resolved!')
  }, 400)
})

const second = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let iter = 7
  for (let i = 1; i < iter; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Iteration: ", i)
    }, i * 500)
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('Second promise resolved!')
  }, iter * 500)
})

first
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .then(() => second
    .then(res => console.log(res)))
```

EDIT: Just to note, the `for` loop will start printing as soon as `second` is defined. If you want to wait for this loop to start, you should add it inside `.then()` so that it triggers after the first promise has been resolved.

Comment: good solution...but the only thing is that "let iter" may change to any number so cant really guess the right time for Timeout

Comment: @johnnybigH I just updated the code to incorporate this behaviour. Hope this helps!

Comment: @johnnybigH Also added a short explanation to the end of my answer.

Comment: Interesting... I need to work on that a bit. Thanks I appreciate!

Answer (score -1):

Well, you call `resolve()` *inside* of your `for` loop. You should place it outside of the `for` loop so that it waits for the loop to finish.

Comment: Calling `resolve()` "outside" the `for` loop won't change anything, as it will still be executed before the `setTimeout()` callbacks are invoked asynchronously.